# React Native UseEffect function is not working according to order

Tags: react-native

***I want to get user's current location and set it into AsyncStorage a array. I will do it in the useEffect hook. But the problem is my functions are not working that according to given order. Here are my code***

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUserLocation();
    setUserLocation();
    check();
  }, []);

  /*Get User's Currunt Location*/

  const getUserLocation = () => {
    GetLocation.getCurrentPosition({
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 15000,
    })
      .then((location) => {
        var lt = location.latitude;
        var lg = location.longitude;
        setlatitude(lt);
        setlongitude(lg);
        console.log("getUserLocation", lt, lg);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const { code, message } = error;
        console.warn(code, message);
      });
  };

  /*Set User's Currunt Location to AsyncStorage*/

  const setUserLocation = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("user_location", JSON.stringify(userLocation));
      console.log("setUserLocation", userLocation);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error setting user location");
    }
  };

  const check = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("user_location", (err, result) => {
      if (result !== null) {
        console.log("check", result);
        setlatitude(result.latitude);
        setlongitude(result.longitude);
      } else {
        console.log("Data Not Found");
      }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use `.then` you are scheduling your code to run at some point in the future, when the promise has completed. So `setUserLocation` runs before the `then` of `getUserLocation`.

Also, it looks like your getUserLocation set react state, which won't be available until the next render. We use effects to manage this.

```
// Get the location on mount
useEffect(getUserLocation, []);

// Whenever the location updates, set it into storage
useEffect(() => setUserLocation().then(check), [latitude, longitude]);
```